# How to view results in a new window without running "%>% View()" at the end of pipeline in R?

Tags: r, view, pipeline

I'm trying to test many result as I add elements to my pipeline so I find a little annoying to add "%>% View" everyhing I need to check for results. Why I don't just select the code I want to view results in a new window? (I know how to use ctrl + enter to run code btw.)

I tried using ctrl and left click but it does not work on pipeline.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: https://github.com/daranzolin/ViewPipeSteps

Comment: Or maybe this package: https://github.com/alistaire47/pipecleaner

Comment: Actually, many more options are listed here as well: https://www.rostrum.blog/2019/04/07/fix-leaky-pipes/